# Reading a RealmObject from another thread

Tags: android, realm

I have a `RealmObject` `User` that I store in a singleton and access throughout the application -- it was retrieved on the UI thread. The object represents the logged in user, and has a one-to-many relationship with the `Item` class. When changing it in a transaction such as in:

```
RealmSingleton.getUserInstance().executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        User user = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("mId",UserSingleton.getUser().getId()).findFirst();
        user.deleteItem(mItem.getClassId());
    }
});
```

This won't work because I'm accessing it inside of the transaction that occurs in another thread. Just to clarify, what I need to do here is store the user's id outside of the transaction and then access that stored variable within the transaction when making the query, like so?

```
Integer userId = UserSingleton.getUser().getId();
Integer classId = mItem.getClassId();
RealmSingleton.getUserInstance().executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            User user = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("mId",userId).findFirst();
            user.deleteItem(classId);
        }
    });
```

Comment: That sounds right, although I do wonder about the implementation of `deleteItem`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce it's just a loop that iterates through the `User`'s `Item` list until it finds one with a matching class id, and when it finds a match it calls `RealmList.deleteItemAt` -- that's it.

Comment: Ah so https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmList.html#deleteFromRealm-int- ? While I prefer to get the element and call `deleteFromRealm` on it, it should work then. What a strange issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. You cannot access an object on multiple threads, so in your case storing a reference to the ID and use that to requery the object is the right approach.