# Realm .NET can't access a realmobject from another thread

Tags: c#, realm

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39686556/10675707) answer, I find out that I can't access a realm object from another thread, but from the answer, I understood that I can store the reference of the realmobject and then use it inside another thread.

I want to loop it until it's inserted but the problem is that I can't access the `var document` and `var s` on another thread.
How then I can find a workaround for that problem?

```
private async void UpdateNotifications_OnAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //UpdateNotification is my RealmObject
    var s = (UpdateNotifications)sender;
    //Here I want to find the document that has the id from my updateNotification
    var document = realm.Find<Document>(s.Identifier)

    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while(!s.Inserted)
        {
            //Here I want to access my document and my S
            string text = queryFinder(document)
            realm.Write(() =>
            {
                s.Inserted = true;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer says you can store a reference to the Id of the object then requery that (use `realm.Find`) on the background thread. It is a bit old though and there's a better way to do it today - using a [`ThreadSafeReference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/dotnet/10.0.0/reference/Realms.ThreadSafeReference.html). That being said, your code won't work because you are using a Realm instance from the main thread on a background thread, which is also disallowed. You would need to refactor it a little so that it kinda looks like this:

```
private async void UpdateNotifications_OnAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var notifications = (UpdateNotifications)sender;
    var document = realm.Find<Document>(notifications.Identifier);

    // Create thread safe references to notifications and document.
    // We'll use them to look up the objects in the background.
    var notificationsRef = ThreadSafeReference.Create(notifications);
    var documentRef = ThreadSafeReference.Create(document);

    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // Always dispose of the Realm on a background thread
        using bgRealm = Realm.GetInstance();

        // We need to look up the notifications and document objects
        // on the background thread from the references we created
        var bgNotifications = bgRealm.Resolve(notificationsRef);
        var bgDocument = bgRealm.Resolve(documentRef;)

        string text = queryFinder(bgDocument);
        bgRealm.Write(() =>
        {
            bgNotifications.Inserted = true;
        });
    }
}
```